# after creating table from parquet file, I can't select a spark column that doesn't exist, but it DOES EXIST?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, parquet, azure-synapse

Going a bit crazy. I have a parquet file I used to make a table like so:

```
  parquetFileDF = spark.read.parquet("abfss://container@storage.dfs.core.windows.net/folder/file.tsv")

  parquetFileDF.write.format('parquet').mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("database.table1")
```

Then if I select * from database.table1 I get:

```
  table1.col1      table1.col2      table1.col3    etc....
```

BUT if I try this:

```
  Select col2 from database.table1
```

I get:

```
  AnalysisException: Column 'col2' does not exist. Did you mean one of the following? [spark_catalog.database.table1.table1.col1, spark_catalog.database.table1.table1.col2,.....
```

What is going on?  On select * I can clearly see my column, and even in the error message, it has the column it says doesn't exist. So how do I save this table so it works like a normal table?

Select * on our other tables doesn't prelead the table1.col and are just col1, col2, col3...
but this one is table1.col1, table1.col2, table1.col3....

I feel like I'm missing something fundamental here.

Comment: Is it possible the column name is `table1.col2` not `col2`

Answer (score 0):

For your query you would need to do

```
parquetFileDF.write.format('parquet').mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("database")
```

Or when you want to keep it

you need to

```
Select col2 from database.table1.table1
```

or

```
Select table1.col2 from database.table
```